# server mointoring / intrusion detection for home nas

Tags: networking, monitoring

I'm looking for some kind of monitor or intrusion detection to monitor my NAS.

The following things I would like to monitor:

1. Incoming network traffic (source -> Router -> NAS) from another country -> E-Mail Alert
2. New users have been created on the system -> E-Mail Alert
3. Unexpectedly high I / O load -> E-Mail Alert
4. monitoring service (Apache, MySQL, etc.) -> E-Mail Alert / Service restart

The service monitoring, point 4, I could solve with Monit. But what about the other points?

Is there something ready or does anyone ideas how something together, for example, could solve with Monit?

For example, to point 2 I might indeed observe changes to a file which all users enthällt eg passwd?

Am grateful for suggestions or solutions.

Comment: Is the NAS a ready-bought system (brand? Model?) or is it home-built? Do you want to implement the intrusion detection system on the NAS itself, or on a separate server?

Comment: the router is a closed (black) box (a router from my provider) named Speedport with a http management interface for simple configurations but with out a terminal or shell. so i would implement the ids on the nas itself

Comment: Well, I would make router log saving to some kind of home server and parse that logs for needed events. And use monit just for port traffic.